# convert strng to integer in pentaho report designer

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-report-designer, pentaho-design-studio

Is there any way to convert the number in to string and concatenate '%' to that number. I tried writing expression for this. But what ever I have written it is giving me 0 value.

like i already had one column with number datatype and I created a new column with the name perc and given '%' to that like below.

total     perc

1           %

2           %

3           %

here some how i have to concatenate this two columns.
Please help me to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using open formula you can convert string into integer and then concatenate.
check sample below

```
=CONCATENATE(INT(field);"%")
```